# Navigation parameter NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, navigation, event-handling, parameters

I'm trying to pass an ObservableCollection from one Frame to the next in a Windows universal app and this is how my OnNavigatedTo looks like:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     var temp = e.Parameter as ObservableCollection<Information>;
     foreach (var item in temp)
     {
          //Do something here
     }
}
```

Problem is everytime this gets called, temp takes NULL value I get an NullReferenceException. Any ideas?

Comment: @Plutonix No. When I put a breakpoint at the e.Parameter it shows me that it contains the entire ObservableCollection

Comment: what is e.Parameter.getType() ?

Comment: If `e.Parameter` is not of the type `ObservableCollection<Information>`, then temp will be assigned `null`.

Comment: Do a direct cast instead of using `as` operator like `(ObservableCollection<Information>)e.Parameter` which will fail if the type doesn't match and throw exception

Comment: You were right..For some very strange reason it has taken my obervablecollectin and transformed it into a System.String...I'm using Template10 for windows universal apps from githab https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/master/Template10%20(Library)  Anyone has used it before??I'm passing the parameter through HamburgerButtonInfo.PageParameter @DarkSquirrel42

Comment: Any ideas ?@hatchet

Comment: Any ideas? @Rahul

Comment: @i_ll_be_back ... SO does not work this way... if you still have a specific question, please open a new, more precise question, and try to give the code for a minimal working example to reproduce your problem